# Tinyscroll bar bad behavior in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using tinyscroll Jquery plugin (http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) for my ASP.NET web app. It works almost fine in Firefox and chrome, but IE doesn't display the scene.

Here is my site address:
http://hightecdev.com/behnoush/Poll.aspx

What is going wrong?

Here is my tinyscroll css

```
/* Tiny Scrollbar */
#scrollbar1 { width: 540px; height:345px; margin: 20px 0 10px; }
#scrollbar1 .viewport { width: 540px; height: 345px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; z-index:100; }
#scrollbar1 .overview { list-style: none; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; text-align:justify; }
#scrollbar1 .scrollbar{ background: transparent url(../images/bg-scrollbar-track-y.png) no-repeat 0 0; position: relative; background-position: 0 0; float: right; width: 4px; }
#scrollbar1 .track { background: transparent url(../images/bg-scrollbar-trackend-y.png) no-repeat 0 100%; height: 100%; width:4px; position: relative; padding: 0 1px; }
#scrollbar1 .thumb { background: transparent url(../images/bg-scrollbar-thumb-y.png) no-repeat 50% 100%; height: 20px; width: 25px; cursor: pointer; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0; left: -7px; }
#scrollbar1 .thumb .end { background: transparent url(../images/bg-scrollbar-thumb-y.png) no-repeat 50% 0; overflow: hidden; height: 5px; width: 25px; }
#scrollbar1 .disable { display: none; }
.noSelect { user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; }
```

Comment: I'm viewing it using IE 8, but IE 9 has the same behavior I think

Comment: I've seen tinyscroll demos working fine in IE, but what is going wrong here?

Comment: Firstly, try to fix this error: Object [object Object] has no method 'inFieldLabels'. Then, testing on emulated IE8/9 and under IE10, i cannot see any difference compare to chrome.